# Delete Custom Content Type Content with Custom Fields

Tags: entities, nodes

I want to delete the content of a custom content type, which has thousand of nodes. The problem is that I can delete the references from the node database table, but the issue in this solution is that the content still remains in the custom field types database table, and when I want to recreate some data, it gives me the error of duplicate data.

Is there a solution to delete custom content type nodes with there related custom field types?

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: So you've deleted your nodes by deleting the entries in the `node` table?

Comment: Not all of them, Almost half.. But when i try to recreate them with old content with some tweaks, it says duplicate content, and after looking in the database, the content is still there..

Comment: Does "delete the references from the node Database table" mean that you ran manual SQL queries to do the deletion and didn't use the Drupal API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code which can be posted in any file and then executed. It will remove all the nodes of the specific content type.

```
// Retrieve all nids for your custom content type.
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :node_type", array(":node_type" => "<YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE>"))->fetchAll();

// Delete all nodes.
 foreach($result as $node) {
  node_delete($node->nid);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `node_delete` or `node_delete_multiple` to do this:

```
// Retrieve all nids for your custom content type.
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :node_type", array(":node_type" => "<YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE>"))
  ->fetchAll();

// Delete all nodes.
foreach($result as $nid) {
  node_delete($nid);
}

// You should also be able to use node_delete_multiple().
// node_delete_multiple($result);
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped but there was an error. I am posting the right code..

Comment: @backTangent - Perhaps you could have asked me to correct the problem instead of making your own answer? I never tested the above code, but I though it would point you in the right direction.

Comment: I only did so that some one coming later should have the right answer, i tried to up vote you but my reputation didnot allowed me.